# Format SSDs through MSI Motherboard MS-7751

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, bios

I ran into a couple of problems and ended up at a point where I cannot boot into Linux nor Windows. I was wondering if there was a way to wipe my drives using MSI's shell and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bootable USB stick or DVD (like a Linux Live CD/USB or a Windows CD) you can easily format what you desire. Through the motherboard BIOS you can't manage partitions etc, only the boot order and only the hardware side of your PC